# How to draw route map in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

[image]

**Problem 1:**  In my project, I have to add the route of a person. for that I have two drop-down from that I can choose the location then add that to my route map by clicking another button called 'ADD'. each time I click 'ADD' after selecting the trips the trip should append the existing route map as shown in the image.

I searched on google but I couldn't find any solution. all are talking about adding line route in google map

**Problem 2:**  we can add Any number of trips, the design should respond accordingly to adjust within the defined dimension.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use **Compodoc**. For documentation, you can read here: https://compodoc.app/guides/routing.html

Comment: let me try this out. thank you